# Cannot stat during kernel compilation error

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

I am trying to compile kernel version 4.10.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 the way described [here](http://www.tecmint.com/kernel-compilation-in-debian-linux/).

It worked up until 4.9.x version.

When 4.10.x came out, I keep getting the following error:

```
install -p    -o root -g root  -m  644 CREDITS /usr/src/linux-4.10.1/debian/linux-headers-4.10.1/usr/share/doc/linux-headers-4.10.1/
install -p    -o root -g root  -m  644 MAINTAINERS /usr/src/linux-4.10.1/debian/linux-headers-4.10.1/usr/share/doc/linux-headers-4.10.1/
install -p    -o root -g root  -m  644 REPORTING-BUGS /usr/src/linux-4.10.1/debian/linux-headers-4.10.1/usr/share/doc/linux-headers-4.10.1/
install: cannot stat ‘REPORTING-BUGS’: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [debian/stamp/install/linux-headers-4.10.1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-4.10.1'
make: *** [kernel_headers] Error 2
```

Comment: Update your question with the exact sequence of commands you used.

Comment: “Cannot stat” just means the file doesn't exist (in all likelihood).

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the kernel developers removed the REPORTING-BUGS file from the kernel source and the Ubuntu tool you used to compile the kernel expects the file to be there.

Apparently most kernel developers don't use make-kpkg, so they either didn't notice or didn't care about the fact that they broke the building of the kernel-headers package with make-kpkg. make-kpkg is after all just the tool of a specific Linux distro and the kernel developers might feel that they never made a promise to always have a documentation file with that path in the source tree.

As a workaround you can just copy the file from the 4.9 kernel sources into your tree to make it compile.